# Default value of argument in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is this default value of argument in es6?

```
function list({ skip = 0, limit = 50 } = {}) {

}
```

What does the above code do?

if it's `list(skip=0, limit=50)` I can understand but now I'm confused.

Comment: Please provide more context. Is `list` a user-defined function or something else?

Comment: @Dai Yes it is a user defined function. I edited his code to add the keywoard function so you won't get confused..

Comment: *"why does above code does?"*... Do you mean *"What does the above code do"*?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That function has [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) mixed together.

Based on the function signature, we can say that we're expecting a single argument, which should be an object.

```
function list(myObject) {

}
```

If no arguments are passed (or `undefined` is passed), we setup a default value to be an empty object, `{}`.

```
function list(myObject = {}) {

}
```

Now, no matter if we pass an object, no arguments, or `undefined`, `myObject` will be an object.

```
// myObject will be {} for all 3 calls
list({})
list()
list(undefined);
```

Next, we destructure this `myObject` by extracting `skip` and `limit` from it:

```
function list(myObject = {}) {
  let { skip, limit } = myObject;
}
```

Furthermore, we can perform this destructuring directly instead of the `myObject` parameter:

```
function list({ skip, limit } = {}) {

}
```

Finally, in case `skip` or `limit` do not exist on the value we end up with, we give them default values:

```
function list({ skip = 0, limit = 50 } = {}) {

}
```

Comment: Just to be a bit clearer: the last snippet gives the default value of {} then the default values for the fields. Ence `list()` will have `skip = 0`

Comment: Yup, is that not clear from my answer? I figured my order of explanation would point this out

Comment: Dunno, I felt it might be a bit confusing, maybe that's just me though.

Comment: list(myObject || {}) why not this? but used equal instead?

Comment: `list(myObject || {}`) is not the same because of 2 reasons. 1) You are giving your argument a fallback value from outside the function, not inside 2) You are using truthiness test for the fallback value while ES6 default values only work when given `undefined` and not for all falsy values.

Comment: so if I call list() and skip is equal to 0 and limit is 50? I got it now.

Answer (score 4):

The function is expecting an object, with `skip` and `limit` properties, and setting defaults if not present. See an example usage below to understand it more clearly

```js
function list({ skip = 0, limit = 50 } = {}) {
  console.log(skip);
  console.log(limit);
}

// No args
list();

// skip changed. Note the object
list({skip: 2});

// limit changed. Note the object
list({limit: 2});
```

Answer (score 4):

It's called de-structuring and it can be tricky to understand if you get caught up with `= {}`.

This is the equivalent in es5:

```
function list() {
  var opts = arguments[0] === undefined ? {} : arguments[0];
  var skip = opts.skip === undefined ? 0 : opts.skip;
  var limit = opts.limit === undefined ? 50 : opts.limit;
}
```

This is very useful for passing configuration objects around and saves us from having to make use of a long list of `x == undefined ? foo : bar`.

---

The reason for doing `{ skip = 0, limit = 50 } = {}` is simply a part of de-structuring. `skip` and `limit` are properties of an unnamed object thus allowing one to simply get the values of the properties without the object reference. You can say they have been injected into the current scope. When we do the `= {}`, then if the right side object (the currently empty one) had a key called `skip`, then the `skip` on the left side gets the new value of the `skip` on the right side. Likewise for `limit`. But since the object on the right does not have properties corresponding to either property names on the left, the left hand properties are left unchanged. Furthermore the use for `= {}` is so that we can have this method called without any arguments, thus the function gets it's default arguments as parameter.

If one is still confused about this, just remember that the only reason for `= {}` is to act as a default parameter for the function which allows us to call the function without arguments. And also, it does not affect the values on the left side of that expression because of the reasons stated.

**References:**

https://simonsmith.io/destructuring-objects-as-function-parameters-in-es6/
https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-destructuring/